# How group item in for TWIG

Tags: symfony, twig

How I can grouping item in list, if I have different items with one ID?

I want if loop find two or more items with the same id combine them in to list `ul > li`.

For example:

[image]

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block wrapper %}
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading clearfix add">
            Заявки
        </div>
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>ID заявки</th>
                <th>Склад</th>
                <th>Матеріал</th>
                <th>Кількість</th>
                <th>Сумма</th>
                <th>Дата</th>
                <th>Час</th>
                <th>Користувач</th>
            </tr>
            {% if itemEntries == null %}
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="6">Елементи для показу відсутні</td>
                </tr>
            {% endif %}
            {% for value in itemEntries  %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ value.id }}.</td>
                    <td>{{ value.bid }}</td>
                    <td>{{ value.storage.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ value.item.name }} (ID: {{ value.item }})</td>
                    <td>{{ value.count }}</td>
                    <td>-{{ value.count * value.item.price }}</td>
                    <td>{{ value.date | date('d-m-Y') }}</td>
                    <td>{{ value.time | date('H:m:i') }}</td>
                    <td>{{ value.userLogin }}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Basically this job should be done in PHP instead (by using SQL queries or `array_filter()`). Use Twig template for representation only. See @Mohamed's answer.

Comment: @Yonel Thank u so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to group the items in a SQL query.

So in you controller you should using `groupBy()` to grouping the result.

Look at this example:

```
$itemEntries = $this->em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('e')
        ->from('AppBundle:Entry', 'e')
        ->groupBy('e.bidId')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

Comment: Thanks you so much!